# Having R ignore an argument in a function

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function for **two types of t-tests** (paired, independent samples). The function takes the arguments `(n1, n2, ttype)`. `n1` and `n2` are sample sizes. `ttype` determines whether the t-test is **paired** (=`1`) or **independent** (=`2`).

How can I make R understand when `n2` is missing or `is.na(n2)`(i.e., `n2= no number in front of it`), take the input as representing a `ttype = 1` and even if there is an `n2` **"ignore"** the `n2` **?**

I'm using the **below code**, but keep getting the error message that:

**"argument "n2" is missing, with no default"**

```
if(missing(n2) | is.na(n2)){n2 <- NA; ttype <- 1}
```

Comment: It looks like you could set `n2=NULL` in the function definition and then test `if(is.null(n2)...`.

Comment: Or `if(length(n2) == 0)...` assuming that `n2=NULL`.

Comment: @eipi10, thanks, let me try this, so you're suggesting defining `n2` as null in the `a <- function(n1, n2=Null, ttype)`?

Comment: Yes. This avoids the `argument missing with no default` error, and then you just test `is.null(n2)` (note the spellings of `NULL` and `is.null`) inside the function to decide which t-test to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work if you use `||` instead of `|`.  With `||` it short circuits, i.e. it works from left to right and only evaluates the right hand side if the left hand side is FALSE; however, with `|` both sides are evaluated first (which results in an error if `n2` is missing) and then it combines them.

```
if (missing(n2) || is.na(n2)) { n2 <- NA; ttype <- 1 }
```